# Obtener el valor del recordset de una consulta MSSQL desde NODE JS cuando la salida es FOR JSON PATH

Tags: json, nodejs, mssql

con el siguiente codigo obtengo una consulta SQL desde node:

```
const sql = require('mssql');

const config = {
user: 'sa',
password: '1234',
server: 'localhost', 
database: 'pruebas',
options: { trustServerCertificate: true }
};

let getAutos = async () => {
  try {
      await sql.connect(config);
      let db = new sql.Request();
      let consulta = `declare @resultado nvarchar(max);
      set @resultado = (select autos.marca, autos.modelo,
            (select especificaciones.especificacion from autos inner join especificaciones on autos.id_auto = especificaciones.id_auto for json path) as especificaciones
            from autos for json path, root('autos'))
      select @resultado`;
      let datos = await db.query(consulta);
      return datos;
  } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
      throw err;
  }
}

getAutos()
.then(datos => {
  console.log(datos.recordset[0]);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(`Hubo un error`);
});
```

el cual me entrega el siguiente objeto:

> {
> '': '{"autos":[{"marca":"Ford","modelo":"Mustang","especificaciones":[{"especificacion":"Potencia: 350 HP"},{"especificacion":"Velocidad: 255 km\/h"},{"especificacion":"Cilindrada: 3500 cc"},{"especificacion":"Peso: 1340 Kg"},{"especificacion":"Potencia: 345 HP"},{"especificacion":"Velocidad: 250 km\/h"},{"especificacion":"Cilindrada: 3700 cc"},{"especificacion":"Peso: 1580 Kg"},{"especificacion":"Potencia: 320 HP"},{"especificacion":"Velocidad: 230 km\/h"},{"especificacion":"Cilindrada: 3900 cc"},{"especificacion":"Peso: 1800 Kg"}]},{"marca":"Chevrolet","modelo":"Camaro","especificaciones":[{"especificacion":"Potencia: 350 HP"},{"especificacion":"Velocidad: 255 km\/h"},{"especificacion":"Cilindrada: 3500 cc"},{"especificacion":"Peso: 1340 Kg"},{"especificacion":"Potencia: 345 HP"},{"especificacion":"Velocidad: 250 km\/h"},{"especificacion":"Cilindrada: 3700 cc"},{"especificacion":"Peso: 1580 Kg"},{"especificacion":"Potencia: 320 HP"},{"especificacion":"Velocidad: 230 km\/h"},{"especificacion":"Cilindrada: 3900 cc"},{"especificacion":"Peso: 1800 Kg"}]},{"marca":"Dodge","modelo":"Charger","especificaciones":[{"especificacion":"Potencia: 350 HP"},{"especificacion":"Velocidad: 255 km\/h"},{"especificacion":"Cilindrada: 3500 cc"},{"especificacion":"Peso: 1340 Kg"},{"especificacion":"Potencia: 345 HP"},{"especificacion":"Velocidad: 250 km\/h"},{"especificacion":"Cilindrada: 3700 cc"},{"especificacion":"Peso: 1580 Kg"},{"especificacion":"Potencia: 320 HP"},{"especificacion":"Velocidad: 230 km\/h"},{"especificacion":"Cilindrada: 3900 cc"},{"especificacion":"Peso: 1800 Kg"}]}]}'
> }

Como puedo acceder al array que contiene el json?

resultado.recordset[0].autos tampoco me funciona.

Answer (score 0):

RESPUESTA:
Consegui la respuesta en el foro en ingles y la dejo aqui por si a alguien le sirve.
Era bastante sencillo, solo habia que darle un nombre a la columna que arroja el select final:

```
select @resultado as algunNombre;
```

y ahi si se puede acceder como:

```
datos.recordset[0].algunNombre;
```